# What is Impl file and under what conditions is the Impl file automatically generated?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making ToDo application with Room Database. I got kaptDebugKotlin build error, so have been find what is cause. Now I find out but there's some problem. I made new project and copied the problem part(Room Database codes) to there. I saw database part's code makes Impl file(ToDoDatabase_Impl.java etc.) automatically in test project and build well, but it doesn't make Impl in my main project and cannot build.

What is Impl file? and under what conditions is the Impl file automatically generated or not?

I changed every annotationProcessor to kapt.

My code is below.

**ToDoDao.kt**

```
package com.overeasy.hiptodo.model

import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface ToDoDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(toDo: ToDo)

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun update(toDo: ToDo)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(toDo: ToDo)
}
```

**ToDoDatabase.kt**

```
package com.overeasy.hiptodo.model

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(
entities = [ToDo::class],
version = 1
)
abstract class ToDoDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun toDoDao(): ToDoDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ToDoDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) : ToDoDatabase? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        ToDoDatabase::class.java,
                        "todo_database"
                    ).build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }
    }
}
```

**ToDo.kt**

```
package com.overeasy.hiptodo.model

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Ignore
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity
class ToDo {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null

    var something: String
    var date: Long?

    @Ignore
    var day: Long? = null

    constructor(something: String) {
        this.something = something
        this.date = null
    }

    constructor(something: String, date: Long) {
        this.something = something
        this.date = date
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.overeasy.hiptodo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled = true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += [
                        "room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental":"true",
                        "room.expandProjection":"true"]
            }
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

    dependencies {
    def roomVersion = "2.2.5"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.20"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.20"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding4:rxbinding:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding4:rxbinding-recyclerview:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"
    implementation "io.sentry:sentry-android:3.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0"
}
```

This is terrible. I've been spent almost 2 weeks to solve this problem. But still can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `toDoDao.insert(someToDo)`, you must ask yourself, how is this code working? abstact `interface` `functions` can't be called, then where is the implementation of `insert(ToDo)` `function`?

Implementation of all the functions defined in the @Dao interface is in the `YourDao_impl` (impl is short for implementation, implementation of your `@Dao interface`) which is automatically generated by the room `annotation` processor.

To appreciate the use of _impl class you must understand that When reading or writing to [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) `databases`, there are multiple steps that needs to be performed almost always. in most cases these steps would look as following:

```
1. Connect to database (In case of android, need to use SQLiteOpenHelper)
2. prepare the query to be executed
3. execute query and receive result
4. build a model from received result (In your case ToDo)
```

But when using `room` you only define an `interface` with `@Dao` `annotation` containing `abstract` `functions` marked with certain `annotations` (`@Insert`, `@Update`, `@Query` etc.). what `room` does is that it automatically generates(using `annotation` processor) the above listed common steps for all your functions.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this sh×tshow!!! This god-damned error was made by `Entity`'s multiple constructor. `Room` accept only one constructor. If someone want 2 or more constructor in `Entity` class, use `@Ignore` annotation above sub-constructor.

P.S. I got `KaptDebugError` and `_Impl does not exist error`. If someone got them although put right dependency in `build.gradle` or did copy and paste exactly, check your `Entity`'s constructor. It's not the veritas, but can be a solution to someone.

Comment: Congrats on figuring out yet another "gotcha" with Room.